# C# y archivos bat

Tags: c#

Estoy aprendiendo a trabajar con archivos bat y C#, lo qe gustaria saber es como puedo hacer q mediante mi aplicacion de windows form ingresar una variable y q ese valor de la variable ingresada vaya al archivo bat

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! Para poder ayudarte mejor necesitamos que compartas el código que tienes hasta el momento. Un saludo :)

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes! Te recomiendo darte una vuelta por el [Tour de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para ver como funciona el sitio y así de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para formular una pregunta de calidad y que esta sea bien recibida.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hay dos formas de realizar la tarea.

La primera, puedes crear una variable global en C# para luego utilizarla en el script BAT a traves de Environment.

```
using System; // 
...
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MIVARIABLE", "valor1");
```

En el archivo BAT podras leerla como %MIVARIABLE%

```
echo %MIVARIABLE%
```

La segunda forma es ejecutar el script batch y enviarle parametros, el cual podras leerlo a traves de %1, %2, etc.

```
string paramUno = "valor1";
string paramDos = "valor2";
string archivo  = "proceso.bat";

System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMSPEC");
startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/C {0} \"{1}\" \"{2}\"", archivo, paramUno, param2);
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

En el script .bat se pueden leer los dos parametros al ejecutarse:

```
@echo off
echo %1
echo %2
```

Answer (score 0):

Si usas la clase `Process`

[Capturar salidas estándar y error al lanzar un proceso con c#](https://muchocodigo.com/capturar-salidas-estandar-y-error-al-lanzar-un-proceso-con-c/)

analiza el ejemplo donde veras que usa

```
Process Proceso = new Process();
Proceso.StartInfo.FileName = "nombre_archivo.bat";
Proceso.StartInfo.Arguments = "aqui irian los parametros necesarios";
```

Puedes indicar el `Arguments` para que al ejecutar el bat asigne los datos

Nota: para acceder a la clase no olvide definir el `using System.Diagnostics`